# Can I make "each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop" warning into an error?

Tags: reactjs

It's reported as a warning, by default. The warning is logged in the console ("Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of `SomeComponent`. See `fb.me/react-warning-keys` for more information.") but no error is thrown and if it's reported from a test, the test doesn't fail, etc. Is there a good way to make this into an error instead of just a warning?

Comment: It looks like [you can't change it to something else than a warning](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f9358c51c8de93abe3cdd0f4720b489befad8c48/packages/react/src/ReactElementValidator.js#L124).

Comment: A (very hacky) way would be to monkey patch `console.error` to intercept this specific error message and throw an `Error`. Another would be to replace the `warning` module that is used to log warnings. Also not the best solution. But maybe you want to assert that the specific test does not trigger that warning or apply that assertion to every test e.g. with [`afterEach()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown).

Comment: what about using eslint and rules to statically detect those cases ? These rules https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-key.md and https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md seem to offer what you need

Comment: @Gonzalo.- that is excellent. If I can find things at "compile time" (well, lint time) instead of runtime I am always much happier :)

Comment: I will post it as an answer hehe

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can lint your code using [ESlint](https://eslint.org/); the following rules should help you to detect the cases you need

[no-array-index-key](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md): Warns the usage of indexes from the array as key

[jsx-key](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-key.md): Warns the lack of key in iteration. If you configure those in your `.eslintrc` as error, it should give you a good coverage of these cases.

```
[<Hello />, <Hello />, <Hello />];

data.map(x => <Hello>{x}</Hello>);

<Hello {...{ key: id, id, caption }} />

things.map((thing, index) => (
  <Hello key={index} />
));

things.map((thing, index) => (
  React.cloneElement(thing, { key: index })
));

things.forEach((thing, index) => {
  otherThings.push(<Hello key={index} />);
});

things.filter((thing, index) => {
  otherThings.push(<Hello key={index} />);
});

things.some((thing, index) => {
  otherThings.push(<Hello key={index} />);
});

things.every((thing, index) => {
  otherThings.push(<Hello key={index} />);
});

things.find((thing, index) => {
  otherThings.push(<Hello key={index} />);
});

things.findIndex((thing, index) => {
  otherThings.push(<Hello key={index} />);
});

things.reduce((collection, thing, index) => (
  collection.concat(<Hello key={index} />)
), []);

things.reduceRight((collection, thing, index) => (
  collection.concat(<Hello key={index} />)
), []);
```

All of these examples will be considered warnings